# How many homophones for "shi" are there in Chinese - with or without considering tones?

Tags: pronunciation, word

I'm curious as to how many Chinese characters correspond to the *pinyin* "shi", such as 是 时 十 事 史 and so on. Is there an exact number of how many words (besides really archaic ones nobody uses) use this pronunciation?

Comment: Dictionaries might help you with this.

Comment: Actually there is a famous article consisting of only "shi" characters called 《施氏食狮史》。https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the info. I found [this audio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vExjnn_3ep4) of someone reading the Lion-Eating Poet in Mandarin on Youtube. Try not to hurt yourself laughing.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[image]

Please see the pictures，the characters in the red box are common used.
The link is https://zidian.911cha.com/pinyin_shi.html
[image]

[image]

Comment: 388 altogether there.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/scripts/wordsearch.php?level=0

Search: "shi" in pinyin  (Mandarin) mode

61 Results:

> (shi1) 濕, 師, 失, 屍, 施....
>
> (shi2) 十, 石, 食, 識, 時....
>
> (shi3) 駛, 始, 屎, 使, 史....
>
> (shi4) 市, 式, 是, 事, 勢....

Answer (score 0):

I often do this.

I use ibus pinyin input method to write Chinese. I set it to display 10 candidates each time. Just enter shi, then press tab until you run out of choices.

For shi I count 237 （23 x 10 + 7 in the last box). There are probably more, but these will be the most common ones.

For someone like me, who has problems with tones, this represents an enormous problem!!

Try this:

季姬寂，集鸡，鸡即棘鸡。棘鸡饥叽，季姬及箕稷济鸡。鸡既济，跻姬笈，季姬忌，急咭鸡，鸡急，继圾几，季姬急，即籍箕击鸡，箕疾击几 伎，伎即齑，鸡叽集几基，季姬急极屐击鸡，鸡既殛，季姬激，即记《季姬击鸡记》。